# Difference between a web application, a web based application and cloud application

Tags: web-applications, cloud

Hi this is a theoretical question, but i really am not able to figure out the difference between a web application, a web based application and cloud based application. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Matt is right - it really doesn't matter, but, for the sake of clarity, here is my definition:

- web application - an application working in a browser, which is not a *web page*, it means that it *does something* - e.g., allows you to share photos
- web based application - as above, but you can think there's an emphasis on the *web*, which means the application doesn't work offline
- cloud based application - here the emphasis is that the logic of the application (the *server-side*) uses some form of SaaS/PaaS/IaaS, e.g., Google App Engine, Amazon EC2, Microsoft Azure or VMWare Cloud Foundry. also this term doesn't indicate the application works in a browser - it may be native mobile (Android, iOS, WP7) application.

Comment: Just to add to this, a cloud based application has three main features which distinguishes it from others - scalability, configurability and multi-tenancy.

Answer (score 0):

Really appreciating both of your answers. Just want to add some more points with @Grzegorz Grzybek & @flamesavor-

The cloud model is composed of 5 essential characteristics, 3 service models and 4 deployment models.

To extends of characteristics model-

- Broad Network access
- Rapid Elasticity
- Measured Service
- On-demand Self Service
- Resource Polling