# What is the technical difference between Web application and Cloud application?

Tags: web, cloud

Are we can call a cloud application as a web application?

if both are not same can any one provide a live example for this..

This question may already have answer here:
[Difference between a web application, a web based application and cloud application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768543/difference-between-a-web-application-a-web-based-application-and-cloud-applicat)

Comment: Well, there's not more to it (beyond fuzzy marketing spin) than in that other question you linked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between a web application, a web based application and cloud application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10768543/difference-between-a-web-application-a-web-based-application-and-cloud-applicat)

Comment: I'd lookup service oriented architecture and go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud application depends on Internet. Where as web application may or may not depends on Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud apps are web apps in the sense that they can be used through web browsers but not all web apps are cloud apps. Software vendors often bundle web apps to sell as "cloud" apps simply because it's the latest buzz-word technology, but web apps do not offer the same richness in functionality and customization you'll get from cloud apps. So, buyer beware!

Some software application vendors also falsely think that just because their application runs on the web, this automatically qualifies it to be a cloud app. This is not always the case. For your web app to evolve into a cloud app, it should exhibit certain properties such as

```
True multi-tenancy to support various requirements & needs for consumers
Support for virtualization technology, which plays a starring role for cloud era apps. Web applications should either be built to support this or re-engineered to do so.
```

VMware Cloud foundry, Google apps Engine, Microsoft Azure, Appcara, Salesforce (Heroku and Force.com), AppFog, Engine Yard, Standing Cloud, and Mendix are examples of such development platforms offering cloud-based technology for building modern applications.